# Convert time to milliseconds using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java

I am trying to write a utility function which converts the accepts date,timestamp,milliseconds additional to timestamp and return the time in milliseconds. However, I am getting a parse Exception for that.

Example params:

dateJson: **14.11.2016**

timestampJson: **21:04:20**

millisecsJson: **244**

```
public static long convertToMillisecs(String dateJson, String timestampJson, String millisecsJson) throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    String inputString = timestampJson + "." + millisecsJson; 
    Date date = sdf.parse(dateJson + 'T' + inputString);

    return date.getTime();
}
```

What has to be changed to get the correct parseable date. It is to be noted that I am using a 24 hour clock and I am based in Germany so using UTC in that case is okay ?

Comment: `14.11.2016` isn't the same format as `dd-MM-yyyy`...

Comment: Change dd-MM-yyyy to dd.MM.yyyy?

Answer (score 0):

14.11.2016 doesn't match dd-MM-yyyy.

And no, Germany is not in the UTC timezone. Use Europe/Berlin.